# how to fix library missing variant issue

Tags: android, android-source, android-soong

I want to add shared library to Aosp broadcastradio@1.1.

but when adding library, following errors occur:

```
cd "$(dirname "out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i "$BUILDER   "     --top "$TOP"     --out "out/soong"     -n "out"     -d "out/soong/build.ninja.d"     -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -globFile out/soong/   .bootstrap/build-globs.ninja -o out/soong/build.ninja --available_env out/soong/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used    Android.bp
error: hardware/interfaces/broadcastradio/1.1/default/Android.bp:26:1: dependency "libtchdradio" of "android.hardware.broadcastradio@1.1-service-lib" m   issing variant:
  os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm_armv8-a_cortex-a53,sdk:,link:shared
available variants:
  os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm64_armv8-a_cortex-a72 (alias to os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm64_armv8-a_cortex-a72,sdk:,link:shared,version:   )
  os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm64_armv8-a_cortex-a72,sdk: (alias to os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm64_armv8-a_cortex-a72,sdk:,link:shared,ver   sion:)
  os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm64_armv8-a_cortex-a72,sdk:,link:static
  os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm64_armv8-a_cortex-a72,sdk:,link:shared (alias to os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm64_armv8-a_cortex-a72,sdk:,lin   k:shared,version:)
  os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm64_armv8-a_cortex-a72,sdk:,link:shared,version:
  os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm64_armv8-a_cortex-a72,sdk:,link:shared,version:latest (alias to os:android,image:vendor.31,arch:arm64_armv8-a_cort   ex-a72,sdk:,link:shared,version:)
16:53:54 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
```

the "libtchdradio" is the shared_library what i want to import.

```
vendor_available: true,
recovery_available: true,
```

it didn't work